# Integrating image with jQuery AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

so I'm working on this project where I'm using jQuery autocomplete to  display search results from a mysql database. The search results are product names fetched from a database which has product images as well.
How would I be able to display the product images like in the image below ?

[image]

Here's my jQuery auto complete page :

```
<script>
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: "search.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {


        log( ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.actor );
         window.location.href = './products/' + ui.item.productid;
         //window.location.href = 'product_display.php?id=' + ui.item.value;
       // document.testForm.action = "pretravel.php?id="+ui.item.value;
        //document.testForm.submit();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php
include 'dbconnector.php';

// Sanitise GET var
if(isset($_GET['term']))
{
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
// Add WHERE clause
//$term="Apple";
$query = "SELECT `productid`, `productname` FROM `products` WHERE `productname` LIKE '%".$term."%' ORDER BY `productid`";


$result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
$id=0;
$return=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    //array_push($return,array('label'=>$row['productid'],'actor'=>$row['productname']));
    //array_push($return,array('value'=>$row['productid'],'label'=>$row['productname']));
    //array_push($return,array('actor'=>$row['productname'],'label'=>$row['productid']));
    array_push($return,array('productid'=>$row['productid'],'label'=>$row['productname']));

}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
//var_dump($return);

exit(); // AJAX call, we don't want anything carrying on here
}
else
{
    header('Location:index');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 13):

There's a method called [`_renderItem`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) that you'd want to use.

Here's a small demo of it in use: http://jsbin.com/cunuxaqe/2/edit

Comment: Could you please give an explanation for that?

Comment: I've edited your code according to my needs but getting this error.
TypeError: $products.data(...) is undefined   
Can you tell me, what could be the possible reason?

Comment: I can't. Not without *at least* seeing the code in question. There's way too many things it can be to try and debug from here.