# Integrate an image to movie titles in IMDb Suggest autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, imdb

I was searching for a way to integrate movie images to their titles in my jQuery auto-complete text-box in my form, and I found [IMDb Suggest](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/imdb_suggest/) quite useful. 
It works perfectly, but the only problem that I noticed is that it returns movie titles, TV-series, actors, directors, etc.. while **I ONLY need MOVIE TITLES.**

### Question:

Is there a way to get only movie titles integrating with their image in my auto-complete text-box (Not TV-series, Not actors, ..)?  (I mean I want to disable auto-complete feature for actors, Series, etc., so if user typed "Tom.." in the search-box, it shouldn't show "Tom Criuse"..)

PS. If it is not possible, How can I show small image of movies when user types a movie name in auto-complete text-box? I have crawled IMDb poster links of movies and saved them in my database. (I saw [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034772/integrating-image-with-jquery-autocomplete), but actually, It didn't use images stored in DB which is my case)

### UPDATE:

In order to avoid TV-series, I crawled list of IMDb movie titles and saved them in my DB. I am trying to compare the string that user enters with the titles in my DB, ao if no match were found it means it is not a movie and it might be g.g., TV-series..

Here is what I changed in suggest.php:

```
if(isset($arr['d'])){
  foreach($arr['d'] as $d){
           try{
              include('imdbconnection.php');
              $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT movieName FROM featuredfilms_EN WHERE movieName = :term");
              $stmt->bindValue(':term', $d['l']);
              $stmt->execute();
              $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

             if (!empty($result)) {

            $img = preg_replace('/_V1_.*?.jpg/ms', "_V1._SY50.jpg", $d['i'][0]);

                if ((strpos($d['s'], "Actor,") === false) {
                       $s[] = array('label' => $d['l'], 'value' => $d['id'], 'cast' => $d['s'], 'img' => $img, 'q' => $d['q']);
                       }   
                 //REST OF THE CODE
```

However, it does not work :|

Comment: You can't just extract titles from the result (http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/imdb_suggest/)?

Comment: @JensonMJohn: sorry, but I didn't understand if your comment was a question or an answer! :p

Comment: It was my question. You told 'it returns movie titles, TV-series, actors, directors, etc' So if it contains title, Why can't you extract just title? It returns as JSON right?

Comment: @JensonMJohn: Well! I don't know how to explain it more :( If you see the suggest.php code in the link that I shared in my question, you may understand my question

Comment: On line 23 (http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/imdb_suggest/suggest.htm?820456607) Change to   $s[] = array('label' => $d['l']);

Comment: @JensonMJohn: I think I couldn't explain my question well... I mean I want to disable auto-complete feature for actors name or TV-Series, so if I type tom.. it shouldn't show me "Tom Criuse".. I hope I could clarify

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63345/discussion-between-jenson-m-john-and-mona).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set condition (Actor, Tv-series, Directors and writers) & filter the results in suggestion page (Line #23)

```
if (strpos($d['s'], "Actor,") === false) { // Here avoiding all actors
$s[] = array('label' => $d['l'], 'value' => $d['id'], 'cast' => $d['s'], 'img' => $img, 'q' => $d['q']);
}
```

Comment: Sorry just one more question: In order to avoid TV-series, I have crawled list of IMDb movie titles and stored them in my database (and NOT TV-series), So I just wonder if it is possible to compare the string that user is typing with these movie titles in my database and if the string didn't found in DB, it means that it is not a movie (e.g, it might be a TV-series)... Do you have any idea?

Comment: I have updated my question, so you can see what I had done.. but it does not work !! )

Comment: @mOna lemme see. Just send a mail to jenson555@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you so much ! What should I sent you by email? Do you need the code of suggest.php or s.th else?

Comment: Ok, but I already out the link of IMDb suggest in my question :p , I will email you now :)