# integrate small image with movie name for autocomplete textbox

Tags: php, jquery, image, movie

I have a PHP form contains some questions. One of the question in this form is : "What are your favourite movies?" for which I used jQuery auto-complete and it work well.

What I would like to do now is to integrate the movie titles with a small image beside it. I stored some IMDb movie titles and also the link to their poster images that I got by crawling.

**My question:** How can I integrate movie images to their titles in the auto-suggest list? 
I read some similar questions like [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034772/integrating-image-with-jquery-autocomplete), but my problem is that my src for the image is not a specific url, but there is a link for each movie in database, for example these are some posterLinks for some movies:

http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg

http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317

http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxMzY3NjcxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTI5OTM0Mw@@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg

This is my code:

```
<fieldset id = "q27"> <legend class="Q27"></legend>
<label class="question"> What are your favorite movies?<span>*</span></label>
<div class="fieldset content"> 
<p>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="movienames">
<a href="#" id="addScnt4">Add more movies</a>
<div id="m_scents">
<p>
<label style="margin-bottom:10px;" for="m_scnts">
<input class="autofill4" type="text" id="m_scnt" size="20" name="q27[]"
value="" placeholder="Enter text" />
</label>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</p>
</div>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  var $title = $('#m_scnt');

  //autocomplete
 $title.autocomplete({
   source: "testfilmsauto.php",
   minLength: 3
   focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $title.val( ui.item.label );
   return false;
   },
   select: function( event, ui ) {
    $title.val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
   }
 });

$title.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  var $li = $('<li>'),
  $img = $('<img>');

  $img.attr({
   src: item.icon,
   alt: item.label
  });

 $li.attr('data-value', item.label);
 $li.append('<a href="#">');
 $li.find('a').append($img).append(item.label);    

  return $li.appendTo(ul);
 };
});

</script>
```

and this is filmsauto.php where I get movies from DB:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
$return_arr = array();

try {
    $conn=new PDO('mysql:dbname=imdb;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT movieName FROM film_Posters WHERE movieName LIKE :term limit 0, 10');
    $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      //    $return_arr[] =  $row['movieName'];
              $obj = new stdClass;
                $obj->value = $row['movieName']; 
                $obj->label = $row['movieName'];
                $obj->icon = $row['posterLink'];
               $return_arr[] = $obj;                    
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

 echo json_encode($return_arr);
}

?>
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

You already have everything you need. What about creating a php array which has the same structure as the one in the demo which you found? Then you have your url and you name.

Just add the column to your query and push an object into your $return_arr:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->value = $row['movieName']; 
$obj->label = $row['movieName'];
$obj->icon = $row['moviePic'];
$return_arr[] = $obj;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but my problem is that I don't know how to create this array with image links in my DB.. :|

Comment: Updated my answer because I can't format it in the comments ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help :), I will try your answer now and will inform you about the result.. Just one more question: I think I have to write your code in my php fie (filmsauto.php), and how can I use the $return_arr[] in javascript file? (because in the sample demo that I mentioned in my question, the array is defined in javascript file... :|

Comment: I have updated my question.. Now you can see what I have done.. I am sure it is not the correct way :(

Comment: Have a look at the output of your filmsauto.php. It displays a json-string. JSON is an acronym for javascript standard object notation, means this is a javascript object. (You can view it human readable on http://json.parser.online.fr/). Now there is just one small typo in your js source, which lets the javascript crash: after minLength: 3 is a comma missing. You can see the parsers output with a web-development console like firebug or sth. For me this works now.